# How to connect circle nodes using arrows?

Tags: javascript, html-canvas

I'm trying to design a simple game where a series of numbered circles can be connected by arrows (like mobile phone pattern locks).

I have these circles designed here:  https://jsfiddle.net/sarmadm/wq8fLphx/

As an example: The user starts from node (1) to any node (e.g node A), then  from (A) to another node . I have designed the circle nodes but I can't workout how to connect them using arrows, how can I make these nodes  connectable?

[image]

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: how can I make these nodes connectable ?

Comment: What do you mean by "making the node connectable"? You can create a function which draws an arrowed line between 2 circles and then call it when you want? If you do not explain what your problem is, what you have tried, etc... I am afraid you will not get the answers you are looking for

Comment: I tried to connect (1 to A) but , I couldn't connect other nodes . My problem is that I want the user able to start a line from node (1) to any other node  until the end of the nodes  , i here what i have tried  : http://jsfiddle.net/sarmadm/96pb9o9s/

Comment: What do you mean by "I couldn't connect other nodes"? What you did looks fine imho. What you should do is make circle an object. It will make it easier to use, you can then add a function which detects which circles the user has selected, and pass the circle objects as arguments of your drawArrow function

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten your code so it uses objects to manage the circles. Try to understand all I have changed before continuing (Note that I have not changed the implementation of your drawing functions, they might need a review too):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Circle(I) {
   I.radius = 30;

   I.draw = function() {
       context.beginPath();
       context.arc(I.x, I.y, I.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
       context.fillStyle = 'white';
       context.fill();
       context.lineWidth = 2;
       context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
       context.stroke();
       context.font = '15pt Calibri';
       context.fillStyle = 'black';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillText(I.label, I.x, I.y);
   }

   return I;
}

var circles = [];

circles.push(Circle({
    x: 369,
    y: 116,
    label: "A"
}));
circles.push(Circle({
    x: 231,
    y: 278,
    label: "1"
}));
// Do above for all your circles

function drawArrow(from, to) {
    var radians = Math.PI / 180;
    var headlen = 10;
    var angle = Math.atan(Math.abs(from.y - to.y) / Math.abs(from.x - to.x));
    var rise = from.radius * Math.sin(angle);
    var run = to.radius * Math.cos(angle);
    context.beginPath();
    if (from.x < to.x) {
        from.x += run;
        to.x -= run;
    } else {
        from.x -= run;
        to.x += run;
    }
    if (from.y < to.y) {
        from.y += rise;
        to.y -= rise;
    } else {
        from.y -= rise;
        to.y += rise;
    }
    context.moveTo(from.x, from.y);
    context.lineTo(to.x, to.y);
    context.stroke();
    context.lineTo(to.x - headlen * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 6), to.y - headlen * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 6));
    context.moveTo(to.x, to.y);
    context.lineTo(to.x - headlen * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 6), to.y - headlen * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 6));
    context.stroke();
}

circles.forEach(function(circle) {
    circle.draw();
});

drawArrow(circles[0], circles[1]);
```

I good improvment now is that it is really easy to move the cicles in the middle of the game : just change their x and y values. Same goes for radius, you can easily have circles with different radius.

Now if you want to make it into some kind of game where the user can select the circles to link them, you might want to add a few things :

1. A game loop
2. Get the user's mouse inputs and find which circles are clicked

Then if you know that the user pressed the mouse on circle B and released it on circle A, you can call the `drawArrow` function from B to A.

Comment: @ realUser404 thanks for correcting my code .  I have added this function for mouse click position  it is not drawing lines from and to click positions , what I should change ?                                                                `function MousePos(event) {
  document.body.textContent =
    "clientX: " + event.clientX +
    " - clientY: " + event.clientY;
    drawArrow( event.clientX,  event.clientY)
}'`

Comment: You should not call drawArrow in the MousePos event imho. What I would do is have a function which detect a mouse press, store the fact that mouse is pressed and which circle is pressed in a variable, then have a function which detects a mouse released, store again which circle, and then if you have both pressed circle and released circle you can call the drawArraw function

Comment: How can I detect which circle is clicked on ?

Comment: This I will let you find by yourself, it should not be too complicated as you have the x and y coordinates of the mouse click

Comment: These are not "classes", not even constructor functions. You're using factory functions.

Comment: @Bálint hum maybe I misused the word "class", I meant it as a way to manipulate entities in a more friendly way than what he was doing. I used the term "class" because it was defined as so on this website : http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: There are classes in javascript, but you use those to create objects, this is what the link meant. Your snippet uses objects.

Comment: @Bálint Ok then, I change "class" by "object" in my answer